# Using GD Star Rating outside of the loop?

Tags: plugin-gd-star-rating

I need to insert a rating straight away after having programmatically created a post in WordPress and added a comment.

What is the (GDSR) function to call to fire the rating once I've got the post id/comment id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
gdsrBlgDB::save_vote($post_id, $user_ID, $ip, $ua, $vote, $comment_id);
```

then insert in the theme:

```
wp_gdsr_comment_integrate_standard_result(get_comment_ID());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about using GD star rating in a theme file like
single.php or page.php you can use a shortcode like so:

```
<div class="rateit"><?php echo do_shortcode('[starrater tpl=10]'); ?></div>
```

You can choose which shortcode to use in the panel
of "create new post"... youll find it in the toolbar.

.

if you are talking about using a file that is completely out of wordpress
you should first "load wordpress framework" like this above everything in the page:

```
require( '../wordpress_install_root/wp-load.php' );
```

And then you the shortcode above...

.

Hope this helps.
Sagive

Comment: Thanks Sagive, but I think this is not the right solution for my problem.

I believe the following code is not the best solution but I've got it working using:

    gdsrBlgDB::save_vote($post_id, $user_ID, $ip, $ua, $vote);

Now I need to see the rating for the post for each voter near their comment.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to print a list of recent comments, along with the rating, and this is the only way I could figure out how to do so outside of the loop.

Since I'm using a custom query to get the comments, here is how I was able to show the ratings with a list of recent comments:

```
<div class="rateit">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[starrater post='.$comment->comment_post_ID.']'); ?>
</div>
```